# Displaying message if no posts in tag

Tags: conditional-tags

I am trying to modify the archive.php file to display a message if there are no posts. I was wondering what the code would be to do this. Here is what i am working with:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">

    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: All those `tribe_*` functions are not Core. I assume those somehow deal with the "tags" you are talking about? If so, post the code. If not, please explain what tags you are talking about.

Comment: removed tribe info to make it easier to understand

Comment: Are I calling `post_meta_read` a "tag"?

Comment: I assume you have a main loop?

Comment: nevermind the tag part, lets just say there are no posts that the archive file can pull in, how do I display a message instead of nothing. I just added the archive.php code from wordpress

Comment: if you review the [Codex for `wp_get_archives`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives), you can see that one of the arguments you can pass in is `echo`. Set `echo` to 0 and assign the function call to a string like `$archive_data = wp_get_archives('type=monthly&echo=0');` and if $archive_data is empty, show a message, otherwise, echo the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems as if you are using loop functions but you don't have a loop. So I've altered your code to include the loops, since it is integral to my particular solution.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">

    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
        </ul>

        <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
        </ul>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- Display "Posts not found" message here -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So basically you are checking to see if any posts exist for the current query using have_posts(). If have_posts() returns true, the loop starts and each post is displayed. If it returns false, it means that this particular query found no posts. Hope that helps.